# Adding icons to Spinner dropdown items in Android

Tags: android, icons, spinner, adapter

I have a spinner with custom theme in my android application. What I need is to add custom icons to each drodown item. The dropdown layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

And I add it to my spinner adapter by this code:

```
zoneAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout....)
```

It is working perfectly. Now I need to add Icons. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: does ``android:drawableLeft`` etc work for you?

Comment: if `android:drawableLeft` doesn't help then explain problem with screen shot

Answer (score 0):

**try this code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_height="40dp">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/spinner_draw"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```